# 3 ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required 1

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am using tkinter and trying to create a library of frames instead of having my program open new windows every time. I have begun creating a welcome page and I am trying to display what I have created only for it to give me this error message. "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk


Large_Font = ("Verdana", 18)

class ATM(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side = "top", fill ="both", expand =True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for i in (WelcomePage, Checking):

            frame = i(container, self)
            self.frames[i] = frame 
            frame.grid(row= 0, column = 0, sticky= "nsew")

        self.show_frame(WelcomePage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class WelcomePage(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, "Welcome to the ATM Simulator", font = Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

        checkButton = Button(self, text = "Checking Account", 
                             command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Checking))
        checkButton.pack()


class Checking(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, "Welcome to the ATM Simulator", font = Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

        homeButton = Button(self, text = "Back to Home Page", 
                             command = lambda: controller.show_frame(WelcomePage))   
        homeButton.pack()
app = ATM()
app.mainloop()
```

The error message is occurring because I state that

`frame = i(container, self)`

but when I create the class I state

`class WelcomePage(tk.Frame):`

The dictionary element in my WelcomePage class only has 1 parameter but I need two. I tried putting `self` as the second parameter but that did not work. This worked in Python 3.4 but now that I am using Python 3.5 it gives me this error. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Checking(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
```

I don't think `Frame`'s initializer can accept that many arguments unless `controller` is a dictionary. Try:

```
class Checking(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

You should also use the `text` named argument to specify the text for your labels.

```
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the ATM Simulator", font = Large_Font)
```